# stat command filesize reporting on busybox

Tags: busybox, sh

I'm trying to write a shell script in busybox to check the filesize of a file.
Having read that stat is more reliable then ls, I decided to use that, but somehow when using the following command:

```
stat -c %s filename
```

I  get the following output: 559795. This goes for the following 2 files (shown using ls -la):

```
0 Jan 20 16:32 foo_empty
4 Jan 20 16:32 foo_not_empty
```

Anyone know what's happening there? I can just go back to using ls, but I'm not understanding what's happening here, and that's bothering me..

Comment: cam you look at the full output of stat with `stat foo_empty` and verify that the 559795 number appears in the size field and not some other field?

Comment: File: "foo_not_empty"
  Size: 559795     Blocks: 559795     IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 98a7bh/559795d Inode: 559795      Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: Fri Jan 20 16:32:29 2012
Modify: Mon Jan 23 10:41:06 2012
Change: Mon Jan 23 10:41:06 2012

Answer (score 1):

if stat is reporting the same odd number for filesize, number of blocks, inode, and device.  I'd suspect filesystem corruption.  You might try fsck and see if it finds/fixes problems.

Comment: This is over multiple disks, so that'd be very weird...

Comment: not as weird as having 1 byte blocks and inode number that happens to exactly match the number of bytes

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
ls -l foo_*
-rw------- 1 fooo users    0 Jan 20 10:30 foo_empty
-rw------- 1 fooo users 3767 Jan 20 10:30 foo_not_empty

busybox stat -c %s foo_empty; busybox stat -c %s foo_not_empty 
0
3767
```

Are you using an old version of busybox, possibly on a 64 bit OS? I'm using

```
BusyBox v1.19.3 (2012-01-03 13:39:53 PST) multi-call binary.
```

Comment: a lot older: BusyBox v1.1.1 (2009.12.24-08:39+0000) multi-call binary. Made the non-empty file a lot bigger, assuming that it was some kind of default filesize, but that does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `stat` is missing from the `busybox` (embedded system). For me, performance isn't an issue, so I ended up with `file_size="$(wc -c ./this-file)"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `du` to check file size. `du -h` will provide you with a "human readable" output.

Comment: This is a good idea, but is not really answering the OP's question.